# Is there a way to align 2 independent axes in an R graph?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I'm plotting a graph with different axis. The problem is that I want the 2 axes to be crossing one point, the rest doesn't really matter. Is it possible?

Here is a reproducible code:

```
plot(x = -10:10, y = -10:10)
abline(v=0,lty = 2)
par(new =TRUE)
plot(x = -10:50, y = seq(-5,5,length.out = length(-10:50)), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty ="n")
abline(v=0,lty = 3)
axis(3, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
axis(4, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
```

Here is the output: 
[image]

I basically want the vertical lines to be crossing each other at 0.

Is there another way to write this (which is not really accurate, I want something that can be done automatically, other than setting a `xlim` manually, since I have a lot of them to do. Also, when the image is resized, it's losing the alignment with the 2 0s):

```
plot(x = -10:10, y = -10:10)
abline(v=0,lty = 2)
par(new =TRUE)
plot(x = -10:50, y = seq(-5,5,length.out = length(-10:50)), 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty ="n",
     xlim = c(-50,50))
abline(v=0,lty = 3, lwd = 5)
axis(3, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
axis(4, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
```

[image]

The output should use something similar to what biplot.prcomp is using to align the arrows and the axis: 
[image]

***EDITED***

With a PCA, it's only working for the y axis, not the x axis.

```
new_lim <- function(a, type = 1) {
  newdata_ratio <-  NULL
  i <- type * 2 - 1
  old_lim <- par("usr")[i:(i+1)] + c(diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * 0.04 / 1.08, 
                                     diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * -0.04 / 1.08)
  old_ratio <- old_lim[1] / old_lim[2]
  newdata_ratio <- if (max(a) <= 0) -1.0e+6 else min(a) / max(a)
  if (old_ratio >= newdata_ratio ) {
    new_min <- min(a)
    new_max <- min(a) / old_ratio
  } else {
    new_min <- max(a) * old_ratio
    new_max <- max(a)
  }
  c(new_min, new_max)
}
s1= rnorm(50,mean = 12)
s2= rnorm(50, mean = 17)
s3= rnorm(50, mean = 20)
library(vegan)
pca=rda(cbind(s1,s2,s3))
pca.scoop=scores(pca, scaling = 2)
biplot(pca)

par(mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))
plot(pca, xlab = "x1", ylab = "y1",
     type = c("p"),
     main= "main",
     scaling = 2,
     choices = c(1,2),
     xlim =c(min(pca.scoop$sites[,1]),max(pca.scoop$sites[,1])),
     ylim = c(min(pca.scoop$sites[,2]),max(pca.scoop$sites[,2])),
     bty = "o",#"l"
     pch=4)
abline(v = 0, lty = 2); abline(h = 0, lty = 2)

x2 <- -10:20
y2 <- seq(40, 10, length.out = length(x2))
par(new =TRUE)
plot(x2, y2, 
     xlim = new_lim(x2), 
     ylim = new_lim(y2, 2), axes = F, ann = F)
axis(3, col = "red", col.axis = "red") # axes=F is equivalent to xaxt="n", yaxt="n" and bty="n"
axis(4, col = "red", col.axis = "red") # ann=F is equivalent to xlab=NA and ylab=NA
mtext("x2", side = 3, line = 2.5, col = "red")
mtext("y2", side = 4, line = 2.5, col = "red")
# box(bty="7", col="red")  # if you want.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to align the second graph based on the first one?

Yes, it is. But it's a litte complex because of needing logical judgment.

This function, `new_lim(a, type)`, calculates first graph's `xlim` (or `ylim`) and ratio of minus to plus from graphic parameters. And it judges which value it uses as second graph's parameter, min(second data) or max, and calculate another value from the first graph's ratio. The output are second graph's min and max value, `_lim`. The argument `a` is a second x or y data. `type = 1` (default; omittable) is for `xlim`, `type = 2` (`type =` is omittable) is for `ylim`.

```
new_lim <- function(a, type = 1) {
  newdata_ratio <-  NULL
  i <- type * 2 - 1
  old_lim <- par("usr")[i:(i+1)] + c(diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * 0.04 / 1.08, 
                                     diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * -0.04 / 1.08)
  old_ratio <- old_lim[1] / old_lim[2]
  newdata_ratio <- if (max(a) <= 0) -1.0e+6 else min(a) / max(a)
  if (old_ratio >= newdata_ratio ) {
    new_min <- min(a)
    new_max <- min(a) / old_ratio
  } else {
    new_min <- max(a) * old_ratio
    new_max <- max(a)
  }
  c(new_min, new_max)
}
```

[Note]
This function needs to exist of first graph and include zero of first data's range. It is no problem that second data's range doesn't include zero.

```
x2 <- -40:20
y2 <- seq(40, 10, length.out = length(-40:20))

par(mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))
plot(x = -15:5, y = -5:15, xlab = "x1", ylab = "y1")
abline(v = 0, lty = 2); abline(h = 0, lty = 2)

par(new =TRUE)
plot(x2, y2, xlim = new_lim(x2), ylim = new_lim(y2, 2), axes = F, ann = F)
axis(3, col = "red", col.axis = "red") # axes=F is equivalent to xaxt="n", yaxt="n" and bty="n"
axis(4, col = "red", col.axis = "red") # ann=F is equivalent to xlab=NA and ylab=NA
mtext("x2", side = 3, line = 2.5, col = "red")
mtext("y2", side = 4, line = 2.5, col = "red")
# box(bty="7", col="red")  # if you want.
```

[image]

#### EDITED  [CAUTION]

When you use this function with plot(class.rda) and change the aspect by Rsutdio, the output becomes different from what you want.

```
x2 <- -10:20
y2 <- seq(40, 10, length.out = length(x2))
library(vegan) 
s1= rnorm(50,mean = 12); s2= rnorm(50, mean = 17); s3= rnorm(50, mean = 20)
pca=rda(cbind(s1,s2,s3))
pca.scoop=scores(pca, scaling = 2)
biplot(pca)
par(new =TRUE)
plot(x2, y2, 
     xlim = new_lim(x2), 
     ylim = new_lim(y2, 2), axes = F, ann = F)
axis(3, col = "red", col.axis = "red")
axis(4, col = "red", col.axis = "red")
mtext("x2", side = 3, line = 2, col = "red")
mtext("y2", side = 4, line = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: That's funny. I'm able to reproduce your code. But when I run a PCA and then try to align the two axes with your function, I'm only able to align the y axis.

Comment: Actually, there is something going on with the aspect ratio, using a pea, that when we rescale the PCA, it changes the ratios that were given in your function new_lim. I wonder if there is a way to correct when the is a aspect ratio that need to be conserved by the plot.

Comment: The problem is when I resize the plot window in the RStudio. This is due, I think, to the fact that the ratio is different when I resize the plot for the PCA and the ratio you have in your function. If you only run the code once, it's working. I guess for the moment it answers the question. 

As you can see with biplot.prcomp, you can resize the plot the way you want, and it's not a problem. The two sets of axis are crossing at 0.

Comment: OK, I grasped your problem and it is reproduced on my environment. But I didn't think of a good idea. If you use `par(pty = "s")`, I guess this function always make  two sets of axis are crossing at 0 like `plot.prcomp()`, but the graph is square...

Comment: I found the method of solving but it makes difference output. The cause of this problem is plot( rda.class ) using arguments `asp = 1`. If you  torelate the asp not 1, you can solve this problem by coping all content of  `getAnywhere(plot.cca)` or `getAnywhere(biplot.rda)`  but `asp = 1` and make your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the way it was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192010/how-to-make-2-axes-cross-at-0-in-rstudio-all-the-time-even-when-resizing-the-pl/38201096#38201096

It's working in it's own now, without changing asp=1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a beautiful solution, but as long as your x-axes always cross the `0` value, you can set the `xlim=c(-max(c(-min(x),max(x))),max(c(-min(x),max(x))))` for both plots.  This will make the x-axis always center at `0`for both the top and bottom axes.  The same can be done with the y-axes if you so choose.

```
# Set graphing parameters
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.1) # This can be reset later with "dev.off()"

# Plot the first graph
plot(x = -10:10, y = -10:10, 
     xlim=c(-max(c(-min(x),max(x))),max(c(-min(x),max(x)))),
     xlab="x-label-1",ylab="y-label-1") # Added labels to be changed
abline(v=0,lty = 2)

# Plot the second graph using new axes
par(new =TRUE)
plot(x = -10:50, y = seq(-5,5,length.out = length(-10:50)), 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty ="n",
     xlim=c(-max(c(-min(x),max(x))),max(c(-min(x),max(x)))),
     xlab=NA,ylab=NA) # Remove x- and y-axis labels
abline(v=0,lty = 3)
axis(3, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
axis(4, col="red",col.axis="red",las=2, cex.axis = 1)
mtext("x-label-2", side = 3, line = 3, cex = par("cex.lab")) # Labeled secondary x-axis
mtext("y-label-2", side = 4, line = 3, cex = par("cex.lab")) # Labeled secondary y-axis
```

which gives:

[image]

I hope this works! You'll need to play around with the values for `par(mar())` if you want to label your graphs with a title.

Comment: Is it possible to align the second graph based on the first one?