# PCA function with axes crossing 0

Tags: r, graph, pca

I want to plot a PCA and center my graph on my points and have a free set of axes that can plot the vectors. I [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133485/is-there-a-way-to-align-2-independent-axes-in-an-r-graph) to align 2 sets of axes, but I need to set the `asp = 1` so that the graph represents equal distances in all directions.

If you copy paste the code below, it's on line 293. I want this `asp = 1`. But when I add it to my code, the 0-0 line is not aligned... especially when I resize it (see image):

[image]

How can I fix this?

```
s1= rnorm(50,mean = 12)
s2= rnorm(50, mean = 17)
s3= rnorm(50, mean = 100)
library(vegan)
pca=rda(cbind(s1,s2,s3))
pca.scoop=scores(pca, scaling = 2)

# Custom PCA plot ---------------------------------------------------------
my_custom_pca <- function(pca = pca, 
                       scaling = 2,
                       choices = c(1,2),
                       zoom=1,
                       square=FALSE,
                       square.size = 1,
                       threshold = 0, 
                       main = 'PCA',
                       pch = 4,
                       col.arrow = "grey",
                       col.label = "red",
                       size.label = .7,
                       col.sites = "black",
                       shape.points = c(17,16,15,19),
                       size.points = 0.5,
                       size.sites = .7,
                       label.the.arrows = TRUE,
                       vector.names = NULL,
                       label.the.points = FALSE,
                       position.text.arrow =1,
                       centered = FALSE,
                       # arrow.centered = FALSE,
                       vector.to.colour.col = 1,
                       vector.to.colour.pch = 1,
                       automatic.col = TRUE,
                       colour.vector = c("#FF3030","#9ACD31","#1D90FF","#FF8001"),
                       ordiellipse = FALSE,
                       rev.x = FALSE, # not done yet
                       rev.y = FALSE, # not done yet
                       transparent.back = FALSE,
                       arrows.different.axis = FALSE,
                       length.arrow = 1, 
                       pca.circle = FALSE,
                       label.figure = NULL,
                       png = NULL,
                       png.w = 9,
                       png.h = 9,
                       res.dpi = 300,
                       pdf = NULL) { 
  if (!is.null(png)) {
    png(file = png, 
        width = png.w, height = png.h, res = res.dpi, units = "in")
  }
  if (!is.null(pdf)) {
    pdf(file = pdf, 
        width = 8.5, height = 11)
  }

  summ.pca = summary(pca, scaling = scaling) 
  pca.scores1 = scores(pca, scaling = scaling, choices = choices)
  prop.exp = round(summ.pca$cont$importance["Proportion Explained",] *100, 2)
  pca.axis.name = c(paste("PC1 ", "(", prop.exp[1], "%", ")", sep = ""),
                    paste("PC2 ", "(", prop.exp[2], "%", ")", sep = ""),
                    paste("PC3 ", "(", prop.exp[3], "%", ")", sep = ""))[choices]
  zoom = zoom
  threshold = threshold # this threshold is to put in the graph only the plants that are far away from the center 
  # (easier to see on the graph), so the one that contributs the most to the variation 

  "pcacircle" <- function (pca) 
  {
    # Draws a circle of equilibrium contribution on a PCA plot 
    # generated from a vegan analysis.
    # vegan uses special constants for its outputs, hence 
    # the 'const' value below.

    eigenv <- pca$CA$eig
    p <- length(eigenv)
    n <- nrow(pca$CA$u)
    tot <- sum(eigenv)
    const <- ((n - 1) * tot)^0.25
    radius <- (2/p)^0.5
    radius <- radius * const
    symbols(0, 0, circles=radius, inches=FALSE, add=TRUE, fg=2)
  }

  line2user <- function(line, side) {
    lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight') *.5
    x_off <- diff(grconvertX(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
    y_off <- diff(grconvertY(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
    switch(side,
           `1` = grconvertY(-line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `2` = grconvertX(-line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `3` = grconvertY(1 + line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `4` = grconvertX(1 + line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           stop("Side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
  }

  addfiglab <- function(lab, xl = par()$mar[2], yl = par()$mar[3]) {

    text(x = line2user(xl, 2), y = line2user(yl, 3), 
         lab, xpd = NA, font = 2, cex = 1.5, adj = c(0, 1))

  }

  # costum alignment of the axes
  new_lim <- function(a, type = 1) {
    newdata_ratio <-  NULL
    i <- type * 2 - 1
    old_lim <- par("usr")[i:(i+1)] + c(diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * 0.04 / 1.08, 
                                       diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * -0.04 / 1.08)
    old_ratio <- old_lim[1] / old_lim[2]
    newdata_ratio <- if (max(a) <= 0) -1.0e+6 else min(a) / max(a)
    if (old_ratio >= newdata_ratio ) {
      new_min <- min(a)
      new_max <- min(a) / old_ratio
    } else {
      new_min <- max(a) * old_ratio
      new_max <- max(a)
    }
    c(new_min, new_max)
  }

  # Draw the PCA with plot.cca
  myccaplot <- function (x, choices = c(1, 2), display = c("sp", "wa", "cn"), 
                         scaling = "species", type, xlim, ylim, const, correlation = FALSE, 
                         hill = FALSE, ...) {
    TYPES <- c("text", "points", "none")
    g <- scores(x, choices, display, scaling, const, correlation = correlation, 
                hill = hill)
    if (length(g) == 0 || all(is.na(g))) 
      stop("nothing to plot: requested scores do not exist")
    if (!is.list(g)) 
      g <- list(default = g)
    for (i in seq_along(g)) {
      if (length(dim(g[[i]])) > 1) 
        rownames(g[[i]]) <- rownames(g[[i]], do.NULL = FALSE, 
                                     prefix = substr(names(g)[i], 1, 3))
    }
    if (!is.null(g$centroids)) {
      if (is.null(g$biplot)) 
        g$biplot <- scores(x, choices, "bp", scaling)
      if (!is.na(g$centroids)[1]) {
        bipnam <- rownames(g$biplot)
        cntnam <- rownames(g$centroids)
        g$biplot <- g$biplot[!(bipnam %in% cntnam), , drop = FALSE]
        if (nrow(g$biplot) == 0) 
          g$biplot <- NULL
      }
    }
    if (missing(type)) {
      nitlimit <- 80
      nit <- max(nrow(g$spe), nrow(g$sit), nrow(g$con), nrow(g$def))
      if (nit > nitlimit) 
        type <- "points"
      else type <- "text"
    }
    else type <- match.arg(type, TYPES)
    if (length(choices) == 1) {
      if (length(g) == 1) 
        pl <- linestack(g[[1]], ...)
      else {
        hasSpec <- names(g)[1] == "species"
        ylim <- range(c(g[[1]], g[[2]]), na.rm = TRUE)
        pl <- linestack(g[[1]], ylim = ylim, side = ifelse(hasSpec, 
                                                           "left", "right"), ...)
        linestack(g[[2]], ylim = ylim, side = ifelse(hasSpec, 
                                                     "right", "left"), add = TRUE, ...)
      }
      return(invisible(pl))
    }
    if (missing(xlim)) {
      xlim <- range(g$species[, 1], g$sites[, 1], g$constraints[, 
                                                                1], g$biplot[, 1], if (length(g$centroids) > 0 && 
                                                                                       is.na(g$centroids)) NA else g$centroids[, 1], g$default[, 
                                                                                                                                               1], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    if (!any(is.finite(xlim))) 
      stop("no finite scores to plot")
    if (missing(ylim)) {
      ylim <- range(g$species[, 2], g$sites[, 2], g$constraints[, 
                                                                2], g$biplot[, 2], if (length(g$centroids) > 0 && 
                                                                                       is.na(g$centroids)) NA else g$centroids[, 2], g$default[, 
                                                                                                                                               2], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    if(rev.x) {
      xlim=rev(xlim)
    }
    if(rev.y) {
      ylim=rev(ylim)
    }
    plot(g[[1]], xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", 
         asp = 1, # I had to remove this so that new_lim work.
         ...)
    # abline(h = 0, lty = 3) # removed
    # abline(v = 0, lty = 3) # removed
    if (!is.null(g$species)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$species, rownames(g$species), col = "red", 
             cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$species, pch = "+", col = "red", cex = 0.7)
    }
    if (!is.null(g$sites)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$sites, rownames(g$sites), cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$sites, pch = 1, cex = 0.7)
    }
    if (!is.null(g$constraints)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$constraints, rownames(g$constraints), cex = 0.7, 
             col = "darkgreen")
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$constraints, pch = 2, cex = 0.7, col = "darkgreen")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$biplot) && nrow(g$biplot) > 0 && type != "none") {
      if (length(display) > 1) {
        mul <- ordiArrowMul(g$biplot)
      }
      else mul <- 1
      attr(g$biplot, "arrow.mul") <- mul
      arrows(0, 0, mul * g$biplot[, 1], mul * g$biplot[, 2], 
             length = 0.05, col = "blue")
      biplabs <- ordiArrowTextXY(mul * g$biplot, rownames(g$biplot))
      text(biplabs, rownames(g$biplot), col = "blue")
      axis(3, at = c(-mul, 0, mul), labels = rep("", 3), col = "blue")
      axis(4, at = c(-mul, 0, mul), labels = c(-1, 0, 1), col = "blue")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$centroids) && !is.na(g$centroids) && type != 
        "none") {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$centroids, rownames(g$centroids), col = "blue")
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$centroids, pch = "x", col = "blue")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$default) && type != "none") {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$default, rownames(g$default), cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$default, pch = 1, cex = 0.7)
    }
    class(g) <- "ordiplot"
    invisible(g)
  }

  align <- function(x) {
    c(-max(c(-min(x),max(x))),max(c(-min(x),max(x))))
  }

  if (transparent.back) {
    par(bg=NA)  
  }

  if (centered) {
    par(mar = c(6,6,6,6))
    x0 = c(min(pca.scores1$sites[,1])*zoom,max(pca.scores1$sites[,1])*zoom)
    y0 = c(min(pca.scores1$sites[,2])*zoom,max(pca.scores1$sites[,2])*zoom)
    myccaplot(pca,
              type = c("n"),
              main = main,
              scaling = scaling,
              choices = choices,
              bty = "o",
              xlab = pca.axis.name[1], ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
              xlim = x0, # pmx,
              ylim = y0, # pmy,
              pch=4,
              axes = FALSE)
    axis(1)  ### (2)
    axis(2)  ### (2)
    box()    ### (2)

    points(pca.scores1$sites,
           col=colour.vector[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.col))], # c("grey","blue") # palette()
           pch=shape.points[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.pch))], # red = AB, green = EG, light blue = magnirostris, purple = scandens
           cex = size.points)
    if (label.the.points) {
      text(x = summ.pca$sites[,1],
           y = summ.pca$sites[,2],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$sites[,]), 
           cex = size.sites, 
           col = col.sites, 
           pos = 1)    
    }
    if (ordiellipse) {
      ordiellipse(pca.scores1,vector.to.colour.col,conf=0.95)
    }
    par(new=TRUE)
    x1 = c(min(pca.scores1$species[,1]),max(pca.scores1$species[,1]))
    y1 = c(min(pca.scores1$species[,2]),max(pca.scores1$species[,2]))
    plot(x = x1,
         y = y1,
         xlim = new_lim(x1),
         ylim = new_lim(y1, 2), # w: 461, h 661 pixels works...
         asp = 1, #Not working with new_lim
         xlab = pca.axis.name[1],
         ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
         type = "n",
         main= "",
         axes = F, ann = F,
         bty = "n")
    axis(3, col="red",col.axis="red",
         cex.axis = 1)
    axis(4, col="red",col.axis="red",
         cex.axis = 1)
    if (pca.circle == TRUE & scaling == 1){
      pcacircle(pca)
    }

    abline(h=0,v=0, lty = 3)

    if (rev.x) {
      pca.scores1$species[,1] = -1*(pca.scores1$species[,1]*length.arrow)
    }
    if (rev.y) {
      pca.scores1$species[,2] = -1*(pca.scores1$species[,2]*length.arrow)
    }
    arrows(0,0, 
           pca.scores1$species[,1]*length.arrow, 
           pca.scores1$species[,2]*length.arrow, 
           length = .1, 
           code = 2, 
           col = col.arrow)

  } else {
    plot(pca,
         choices = choices,
         type = c("n"),
         xlab = pca.axis.name[1],
         ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
         main= main,
         scaling = scaling,
         pch=4)
    points(pca.scores1$sites,
           col=colour.vector[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.col))], # c("grey","blue") # palette()
           pch=shape.points[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.pch))], # red = AB, green = EG, light blue = magnirostris, purple = scandens
           cex = size.points)
    if (rev.x) {
      summ.pca$species[,1] = rev(summ.pca$species[,1])
    }
    if (rev.y) {
      summ.pca$species[,1] = rev(summ.pca$species[,1])
    }
    arrows(0,0, 
           summ.pca$species[,choices[1]], 
           summ.pca$species[,choices[2]], 
           length = .1, 
           code = 2, 
           col = col.arrow)
    if (pca.circle == TRUE & scaling == 1){
      pcacircle(pca)
    }
    if (ordiellipse) {
      ordiellipse(pca.scores1,vector.to.colour.col,conf=0.95)
    }
  }

  if (rev.x) {
    summ.pca$species[,1] = -1*(summ.pca$species[,1])
  }
  if (rev.y) {
    summ.pca$species[,2] = -1*(summ.pca$species[,2])
  }
  if (!(length(small))) {
    if (label.the.arrows) {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$species[,]), 
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    } else {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = vector.names, 
           pos = position.text.arrow,
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    }
  } else {
    if (label.the.arrows) {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[-small,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[-small,choices[2]],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$species[-small,]), 
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    } else {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = vector.names, 
           pos = position.text.arrow,
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    }
  }

  if (rev.x) {
    summ.pca$sites[,1] = -1*(summ.pca$sites[,1])
  }
  if (rev.y) {
    summ.pca$sites[,2] = -1*(summ.pca$sites[,2])
  }
  if (label.the.points & !centered) {
    text(x = summ.pca$sites[,1],
         y = summ.pca$sites[,2],
         labels = row.names(summ.pca$sites[,]), 
         cex = size.sites, 
         col = col.sites, 
         pos = 1)  
  }
  if (square) {
    abline(h = c(-square.size,square.size), 
           v = c(-square.size,square.size), 
           lty = 3)
  }

  if (!is.null(png)|!is.null(pdf)) {
    dev.off()

  }
  if (!(!length(label.figure))) {
    addfiglab(label.figure)
  }
}


my_custom_pca(pca, centered = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made `new_xylim()` that partly solves your problem. This function calculates second graph's `xlim()` and `ylim()` to align 2 sets of axes and set the same scale of 2nd x and y. Please use it instead of `new_lim()`.
When you use `asp=1` at both first and second graph and resize an output, I think there are four patterns (dependence on data): (1) change of `axis(1)` and `axis(3)`, (2) `axis(2)` and `axis(4)`, (3) `axis(1)` but not `axis(3)`, or the reverse, (4) `axis(2)` but not `axis(4)`, or the reverse. When (3) or (4), it is difficult to realize what you want, so please change device size before output instead of resizing.

only `new_xylim()`;

```
new_xylim <- function(x2, y2) {
  # new_lim2() calculates xlim or ylim in view of only alignment.
  new_lim2 <- function(a, type = 1, ratio = FALSE) {
    new_ratio <-  NULL            # type=1 is for xlim, 2 is for ylim.
    i <- type * 2 - 1
    old_lim <- par("usr")[i:(i+1)] + c(diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * 0.04 / 1.08, 
                                       diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * -0.04 / 1.08)
    old_ratio <- diff(old_lim) / (-1 * old_lim[1])
    new_ratio <- if (min(a) >= 0) 1.0e+6 else diff(range(a)) / (-1 * min(a))
    if (old_ratio >= new_ratio) {
      new_min <- min(a)
      new_max <- abs(min(a)) * (old_ratio - 1)
    } else {
      new_min <- abs(max(a)) / (old_ratio - 1) * -1
      new_max <- max(a)
    }
    if (ratio) return(old_ratio) else return(c(new_min, new_max))
  }

  temp_x <- new_lim2(x2, type=1)  # calculation of needing range
  temp_y <- new_lim2(y2, type=2)

  if (par("pin")[1] / diff(temp_x) >= par("pin")[2] / diff(temp_y)) {
    # logical judgment of which range is expanded under the same scale
    new_ylim <- temp_y                     # the one range isn't expanded.
    new_xdiff <- par("pin")[1] * diff(new_ylim) / par("pin")[2]  # calculation of the another expanded range
    old_xratio <- new_lim2(x2, type = 1, ratio = TRUE)           # information about zero position
    new_xlim <- c(-1 * new_xdiff / old_xratio, new_xdiff - new_xdiff / old_xratio) # calculation of _lim by the zero position and the expanded range
  } else {
    new_xlim <- temp_x
    new_ydiff <- par("pin")[2] * diff(new_xlim) / par("pin")[1]
    old_yratio <- new_lim2(y2, type=2, ratio = TRUE)
    new_ylim <- c(-1 * new_ydiff / old_yratio, new_ydiff - new_ydiff / old_yratio)
  }
  return(list(new_xlim, new_ylim))
}
```

an example of `new_xylim()`;

```
x2 <- -1:3
y2 <- seq(-100, 30, length=5)

plot(-5:5, -1:9, ann=F, asp=1)
par(new=T)
plot(x2, y2, xlim=new_xylim(x2, y2)[[1]], ylim=new_xylim(x2, y2)[[2]], ann=F, axes=F, asp=1)
axis(3); axis(4); abline(h=0); abline(v=0) # if you don't resize, second graph's asp=1 is unnecessary.
```

[image]

modified your `function()` (I also added argument `small = NULL` to suppress error);

```
# Custom PCA plot ---------------------------------------------------------
my_custom_pca2 <- function(pca = pca, 
                           scaling = 2,
                           choices = c(1,2),
                           zoom=1,
                           square=FALSE,
                           square.size = 1,
                           threshold = 0, 
                           main = 'PCA',
                           pch = 4,
                           col.arrow = "grey",
                           col.label = "red",
                           size.label = .7,
                           col.sites = "black",
                           shape.points = c(17,16,15,19),
                           size.points = 0.5,
                           size.sites = .7,
                           label.the.arrows = TRUE,
                           vector.names = NULL,
                           label.the.points = FALSE,
                           position.text.arrow =1,
                           centered = FALSE,
                           # arrow.centered = FALSE,
                           vector.to.colour.col = 1,
                           vector.to.colour.pch = 1,
                           automatic.col = TRUE,
                           colour.vector = c("#FF3030","#9ACD31","#1D90FF","#FF8001"),
                           ordiellipse = FALSE,
                           rev.x = FALSE, # not done yet
                           rev.y = FALSE, # not done yet
                           transparent.back = FALSE,
                           arrows.different.axis = FALSE,
                           length.arrow = 1, 
                           pca.circle = FALSE,
                           label.figure = NULL,
                           png = NULL,
                           png.w = 9,
                           png.h = 9,
                           res.dpi = 300,
                           pdf = NULL,
                           small = NULL) {            ### modified
  if (!is.null(png)) {
    png(file = png, 
        width = png.w, height = png.h, res = res.dpi, units = "in")
  }
  if (!is.null(pdf)) {
    pdf(file = pdf, 
        width = 8.5, height = 11)
  }

  summ.pca = summary(pca, scaling = scaling) 
  pca.scores1 = scores(pca, scaling = scaling, choices = choices)
  prop.exp = round(summ.pca$cont$importance["Proportion Explained",] *100, 2)
  pca.axis.name = c(paste("PC1 ", "(", prop.exp[1], "%", ")", sep = ""),
                    paste("PC2 ", "(", prop.exp[2], "%", ")", sep = ""),
                    paste("PC3 ", "(", prop.exp[3], "%", ")", sep = ""))[choices]
  zoom = zoom
  threshold = threshold # this threshold is to put in the graph only the plants that are far away from the center 
  # (easier to see on the graph), so the one that contributs the most to the variation 

  "pcacircle" <- function (pca) 
  {
    # Draws a circle of equilibrium contribution on a PCA plot 
    # generated from a vegan analysis.
    # vegan uses special constants for its outputs, hence 
    # the 'const' value below.

    eigenv <- pca$CA$eig
    p <- length(eigenv)
    n <- nrow(pca$CA$u)
    tot <- sum(eigenv)
    const <- ((n - 1) * tot)^0.25
    radius <- (2/p)^0.5
    radius <- radius * const
    symbols(0, 0, circles=radius, inches=FALSE, add=TRUE, fg=2)
  }

  line2user <- function(line, side) {
    lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight') *.5
    x_off <- diff(grconvertX(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
    y_off <- diff(grconvertY(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
    switch(side,
           `1` = grconvertY(-line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `2` = grconvertX(-line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `3` = grconvertY(1 + line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           `4` = grconvertX(1 + line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
           stop("Side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
  }

  addfiglab <- function(lab, xl = par()$mar[2], yl = par()$mar[3]) {

    text(x = line2user(xl, 2), y = line2user(yl, 3), 
         lab, xpd = NA, font = 2, cex = 1.5, adj = c(0, 1))

  }

  # costum alignment of the axes
  new_xylim <- function(x2, y2) {                      ### modified
    new_lim2 <- function(a, type = 1, ratio = FALSE) {
      new_ratio <-  NULL
      i <- type * 2 - 1
      old_lim <- par("usr")[i:(i+1)] + c(diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * 0.04 / 1.08, 
                                         diff(par("usr")[i:(i+1)]) * -0.04 / 1.08)
      old_ratio <- diff(old_lim) / (-1 * old_lim[1])
      new_ratio <- if (min(a) >= 0) 1.0e+6 else diff(range(a)) / (-1 * min(a))
      if (old_ratio >= new_ratio) {
        new_min <- min(a)
        new_max <- abs(min(a)) * (old_ratio - 1)
      } else {
        new_min <- abs(max(a)) / (old_ratio - 1) * -1
        new_max <- max(a)
      }
      if (ratio) return(old_ratio) else return(c(new_min, new_max))
    }
    temp_x <- new_lim2(x2, type=1)
    temp_y <- new_lim2(y2, type=2)
    if (par("pin")[1] / diff(temp_x) >= par("pin")[2] / diff(temp_y)) {
      new_ylim <- temp_y
      new_xdiff <- par("pin")[1] * diff(new_ylim) / par("pin")[2]
      old_xratio <- new_lim2(x2, type = 1, ratio = TRUE)
      new_xlim <- c(-1 * new_xdiff / old_xratio, new_xdiff - new_xdiff / old_xratio)
    } else {
      new_xlim <- temp_x
      new_ydiff <- par("pin")[2] * diff(new_xlim) / par("pin")[1]
      old_yratio <- new_lim2(y2, type=2, ratio = TRUE)
      new_ylim <- c(-1 * new_ydiff / old_yratio, new_ydiff - new_ydiff / old_yratio)
    }
    return(list(new_xlim, new_ylim))
  }

  # Draw the PCA with plot.cca
  myccaplot <- function (x, choices = c(1, 2), display = c("sp", "wa", "cn"), 
                         scaling = "species", type, xlim, ylim, const, correlation = FALSE, 
                         hill = FALSE, ...) {
    TYPES <- c("text", "points", "none")
    g <- scores(x, choices, display, scaling, const, correlation = correlation, 
                hill = hill)
    if (length(g) == 0 || all(is.na(g))) 
      stop("nothing to plot: requested scores do not exist")
    if (!is.list(g)) 
      g <- list(default = g)
    for (i in seq_along(g)) {
      if (length(dim(g[[i]])) > 1) 
        rownames(g[[i]]) <- rownames(g[[i]], do.NULL = FALSE, 
                                     prefix = substr(names(g)[i], 1, 3))
    }
    if (!is.null(g$centroids)) {
      if (is.null(g$biplot)) 
        g$biplot <- scores(x, choices, "bp", scaling)
      if (!is.na(g$centroids)[1]) {
        bipnam <- rownames(g$biplot)
        cntnam <- rownames(g$centroids)
        g$biplot <- g$biplot[!(bipnam %in% cntnam), , drop = FALSE]
        if (nrow(g$biplot) == 0) 
          g$biplot <- NULL
      }
    }
    if (missing(type)) {
      nitlimit <- 80
      nit <- max(nrow(g$spe), nrow(g$sit), nrow(g$con), nrow(g$def))
      if (nit > nitlimit) 
        type <- "points"
      else type <- "text"
    }
    else type <- match.arg(type, TYPES)
    if (length(choices) == 1) {
      if (length(g) == 1) 
        pl <- linestack(g[[1]], ...)
      else {
        hasSpec <- names(g)[1] == "species"
        ylim <- range(c(g[[1]], g[[2]]), na.rm = TRUE)
        pl <- linestack(g[[1]], ylim = ylim, side = ifelse(hasSpec, 
                                                           "left", "right"), ...)
        linestack(g[[2]], ylim = ylim, side = ifelse(hasSpec, 
                                                     "right", "left"), add = TRUE, ...)
      }
      return(invisible(pl))
    }
    if (missing(xlim)) {
      xlim <- range(g$species[, 1], g$sites[, 1], g$constraints[, 
                                                                1], g$biplot[, 1], if (length(g$centroids) > 0 && 
                                                                                       is.na(g$centroids)) NA else g$centroids[, 1], g$default[, 
                                                                                                                                               1], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    if (!any(is.finite(xlim))) 
      stop("no finite scores to plot")
    if (missing(ylim)) {
      ylim <- range(g$species[, 2], g$sites[, 2], g$constraints[, 
                                                                2], g$biplot[, 2], if (length(g$centroids) > 0 && 
                                                                                       is.na(g$centroids)) NA else g$centroids[, 2], g$default[, 
                                                                                                                                               2], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    if(rev.x) {
      xlim=rev(xlim)
    }
    if(rev.y) {
      ylim=rev(ylim)
    }
    plot(g[[1]], xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", 
         asp = 1, # I had to remove this so that new_lim work.
         ...)
    # abline(h = 0, lty = 3) # removed
    # abline(v = 0, lty = 3) # removed
    if (!is.null(g$species)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$species, rownames(g$species), col = "red", 
             cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$species, pch = "+", col = "red", cex = 0.7)
    }
    if (!is.null(g$sites)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$sites, rownames(g$sites), cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$sites, pch = 1, cex = 0.7)
    }
    if (!is.null(g$constraints)) {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$constraints, rownames(g$constraints), cex = 0.7, 
             col = "darkgreen")
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$constraints, pch = 2, cex = 0.7, col = "darkgreen")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$biplot) && nrow(g$biplot) > 0 && type != "none") {
      if (length(display) > 1) {
        mul <- ordiArrowMul(g$biplot)
      }
      else mul <- 1
      attr(g$biplot, "arrow.mul") <- mul
      arrows(0, 0, mul * g$biplot[, 1], mul * g$biplot[, 2], 
             length = 0.05, col = "blue")
      biplabs <- ordiArrowTextXY(mul * g$biplot, rownames(g$biplot))
      text(biplabs, rownames(g$biplot), col = "blue")
      axis(3, at = c(-mul, 0, mul), labels = rep("", 3), col = "blue")
      axis(4, at = c(-mul, 0, mul), labels = c(-1, 0, 1), col = "blue")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$centroids) && !is.na(g$centroids) && type != 
        "none") {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$centroids, rownames(g$centroids), col = "blue")
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$centroids, pch = "x", col = "blue")
    }
    if (!is.null(g$default) && type != "none") {
      if (type == "text") 
        text(g$default, rownames(g$default), cex = 0.7)
      else if (type == "points") 
        points(g$default, pch = 1, cex = 0.7)
    }
    class(g) <- "ordiplot"
    invisible(g)
  }

  align <- function(x) {
    c(-max(c(-min(x),max(x))),max(c(-min(x),max(x))))
  }

  if (transparent.back) {
    par(bg=NA)  
  }

  if (centered) {
    par(mar = c(6,6,6,6))
    x0 = c(min(pca.scores1$sites[,1])*zoom,max(pca.scores1$sites[,1])*zoom)
    y0 = c(min(pca.scores1$sites[,2])*zoom,max(pca.scores1$sites[,2])*zoom)
    myccaplot(pca,
              type = c("n"),
              main = main,
              scaling = scaling,
              choices = choices,
              bty = "o",
              xlab = pca.axis.name[1], ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
              xlim = x0, # pmx,
              ylim = y0, # pmy,
              pch=4,
              axes = FALSE)
    axis(1)  ### (2)
    axis(2)  ### (2)
    box()    ### (2)

    points(pca.scores1$sites,
           col=colour.vector[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.col))], # c("grey","blue") # palette()
           pch=shape.points[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.pch))], # red = AB, green = EG, light blue = magnirostris, purple = scandens
           cex = size.points)
    if (label.the.points) {
      text(x = summ.pca$sites[,1],
           y = summ.pca$sites[,2],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$sites[,]), 
           cex = size.sites, 
           col = col.sites, 
           pos = 1)    
    }
    if (ordiellipse) {
      ordiellipse(pca.scores1,vector.to.colour.col,conf=0.95)
    }
    par(new=TRUE)
    x1 = c(min(pca.scores1$species[,1]),max(pca.scores1$species[,1]))
    y1 = c(min(pca.scores1$species[,2]),max(pca.scores1$species[,2]))
    plot(x = x1,
         y = y1,
         xlim = new_xylim(x1, y1)[[1]],             ### modified
         ylim = new_xylim(x1, y1)[[2]],             ### modified
         asp = 1, 
         xlab = pca.axis.name[1],
         ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
         type = "n",
         main= "",
         axes = F, ann = F,
         bty = "n")
    axis(3, col="red",col.axis="red",
         cex.axis = 1)
    axis(4, col="red",col.axis="red",
         cex.axis = 1)
    if (pca.circle == TRUE & scaling == 1){
      pcacircle(pca)
    }

    abline(h=0,v=0, lty = 3)

    if (rev.x) {
      pca.scores1$species[,1] = -1*(pca.scores1$species[,1]*length.arrow)
    }
    if (rev.y) {
      pca.scores1$species[,2] = -1*(pca.scores1$species[,2]*length.arrow)
    }
    arrows(0,0, 
           pca.scores1$species[,1]*length.arrow, 
           pca.scores1$species[,2]*length.arrow, 
           length = .1, 
           code = 2, 
           col = col.arrow)

  } else {
    plot(pca,
         choices = choices,
         type = c("n"),
         xlab = pca.axis.name[1],
         ylab = pca.axis.name[2],
         main= main,
         scaling = scaling,
         pch=4)
    points(pca.scores1$sites,
           col=colour.vector[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.col))], # c("grey","blue") # palette()
           pch=shape.points[(as.numeric(vector.to.colour.pch))], # red = AB, green = EG, light blue = magnirostris, purple = scandens
           cex = size.points)
    if (rev.x) {
      summ.pca$species[,1] = rev(summ.pca$species[,1])
    }
    if (rev.y) {
      summ.pca$species[,1] = rev(summ.pca$species[,1])
    }
    arrows(0,0, 
           summ.pca$species[,choices[1]], 
           summ.pca$species[,choices[2]], 
           length = .1, 
           code = 2, 
           col = col.arrow)
    if (pca.circle == TRUE & scaling == 1){
      pcacircle(pca)
    }
    if (ordiellipse) {
      ordiellipse(pca.scores1,vector.to.colour.col,conf=0.95)
    }
  }

  if (rev.x) {
    summ.pca$species[,1] = -1*(summ.pca$species[,1])
  }
  if (rev.y) {
    summ.pca$species[,2] = -1*(summ.pca$species[,2])
  }
  if (!(length(small))) {
    if (label.the.arrows) {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$species[,]), 
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    } else {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = vector.names, 
           pos = position.text.arrow,
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    }
  } else {
    if (label.the.arrows) {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[-small,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[-small,choices[2]],
           labels = row.names(summ.pca$species[-small,]), 
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    } else {
      text(x = summ.pca$species[,choices[1]],
           y = summ.pca$species[,choices[2]],
           labels = vector.names, 
           pos = position.text.arrow,
           cex = size.label, 
           col = col.label)
    }
  }

  if (rev.x) {
    summ.pca$sites[,1] = -1*(summ.pca$sites[,1])
  }
  if (rev.y) {
    summ.pca$sites[,2] = -1*(summ.pca$sites[,2])
  }
  if (label.the.points & !centered) {
    text(x = summ.pca$sites[,1],
         y = summ.pca$sites[,2],
         labels = row.names(summ.pca$sites[,]), 
         cex = size.sites, 
         col = col.sites, 
         pos = 1)  
  }
  if (square) {
    abline(h = c(-square.size,square.size), 
           v = c(-square.size,square.size), 
           lty = 3)
  }

  if (!is.null(png)|!is.null(pdf)) {
    dev.off()

  }
  if (!(!length(label.figure))) {
    addfiglab(label.figure)
  }
}
```

using it;

```
set.seed(1); s1= rnorm(50,mean = 12)
set.seed(10); s2= rnorm(50, mean = 17)
set.seed(100); s3= rnorm(50, mean = 100)
library(vegan)
pca=rda(cbind(s1,s2,s3))
pca.scoop=scores(pca, scaling = 2)

my_custom_pca2(pca, centered = TRUE)

par("pin")[1]/diff(par("usr")[1:2])
par("pin")[2]/diff(par("usr")[3:4]) # the same
```

[image]

In this case on my environment (640 x 500), I can resize the width larger and/or the height smaller  (change of `axis(1)` and `axis(3)`) but can't the width smaller and/or the height larger (change of `axis(1)` but not `axis(3)`).

[image]
[image]

Comment: But I think that when you export it directly from the `pdf()`, `png()` or `jpeg()` function, you don't have this problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: @M. Beausoleil; I'm glad I could help you. I edited out a few unnecessary code but you needn't pay attention because output doesn't differ from before .